# How to draw this graph

Tags: pgfplots

It is first time for me using latex. I am trying to draw this figure . This is my code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      xmin=-5,xmax=5,
      axis y line*=left,
      \addplot {x^2};
    \end{axis}
    \begin{axis}[
      xmin=0,xmax=15,
      domain=0:15,
      \addplot[red] {x};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: looks like you already did. What is wrong with it?

Comment: @percusse I could not attached  the figure which I want to draw.

Comment: After adding the image, remove the initial `!`, we can later add it for you until you get more rep points.

Answer (score 6):

You just forget to close axis option with `]`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      xmin=-5,xmax=5,
      axis y line*=left,
                ]% <--- added
      \addplot {x^2};
    \end{axis}
    \begin{axis}[
      xmin=0,xmax=15,
      domain=0:15,
                ]% <--- added
      \addplot[red] {x};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Although I suspect the problem were the mangled axis...